# Auto defragmentation of SSD

Tags: ssd, windows-server-2003, defragment

I added a SSD to a 2003 server. I heard there is some kind of auto defrag in windows which is disabled for SSDs from windows 7 only.

Is there a way to disable the auto defrag in Windows 2003 Server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have win2k3 at the moment so I can't give exact instructions, but you could always take a look at scheduled tasks (it should be in accessories in start menu if I remember correctly) and find auto defragmentation if ti's there. I'm not 100% sure that win2k3 has automatic defragmentation scheduled.

EDIT: I just found an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=169) about enabling automatic defragmentation in windows server 2003, so I'd say it's not enabled by default. I could be wrong, so it would be best to check to make sure that the task isn't there for partitions on the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late on the response but for anyone else who may be interested the auto defrag in in exchange not 2003 server and it is still required because it is a database degraf not a disk defrag

Answer (score -1):

Shut down any defragmentation on your ssd.  It creates excessive and unnecessary writes which lessens the life of the drive

Comment: Way to actually read the question...